# How to align the HelperText in center?

Tags: flutter, dart

TextFormField has a hintText and a HelperText , but i can seem to find a way to align the helperText in center , this is my code :

```
child: Container(

                  child: TextFormField(
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 21),
                    decoration: InputDecoration(

                      hintText: "hint text",
                      focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(

                          borderSide: BorderSide(color: primaryColor)),
                      helperText: "THIS IS THE HELPER TEXT TO BE ALIGNED ",
                       

                      helperStyle:
                          TextStyle(color: oASDC, fontSize: 15),

                    ),
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      setState(() {.......});
                    },
                  ),
                ),
```

is there a way to align the helper text in center?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You try this way:

> https://i.stack.imgur.com/7LFJc.png

```
return TextFormField(
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 21),
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 50, right: 50),
        hintText: "hint text",
        focusedBorder:
            UnderlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.green)),
        helperText: "THIS IS THE HELPER TEXT TO BE ALIGNED ",
        helperStyle: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.blue,
          fontSize: 15,
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand the position of the `helperText` is like the position of the `errorText`,

[issue 1](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/21343)
[issue 2](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/11068)

according to these issues, there seems to be no solution to this.

However, if you only need text , you can easily add `Text` widget below the `TextFormField`

like so:

```
Container(
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    TextFormField(
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 21),
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: "hint text",
                        focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide(color: primaryColor),),
                        // helperText: "THIS IS THE HELPER TEXT TO BE ALIGNED ",

                        helperStyle: TextStyle(color: oASDC, fontSize: 15),
                      ),
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        // setState(() {.......});
                      },
                    ),
                    Text(
                      'THIS IS THE HELPER TEXT TO BE ALIGNED',
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is nothing conventional to align the helpertext.
Use `contentPadding` instead, not a proper way, but it's a day saver!

```
  Container(
    child: TextFormField(
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 21),
      decoration: InputDecoration(
          hintText: "hint text",
          focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.yellow)),
          helperText: "THIS IS THE HELPER TEXT TO BE ALIGNED ",
          helperStyle: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.red,
            fontSize: 15,
          ),
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25)),
      onChanged: (value) {
        print(value);
      },
    ),
  ),
```